# node.js local modules :cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, module

I am trying to implement local modules in my application

1.Project root folder i have created folder named `test`  with a file named  `index.js`

```
      module.exports  = {

     myFunction:function(){
       console.log('ok');
     }
}
```

2.Added the following in `package.json` in the root folder

```
"dependencies": { 
    "test-module": "file:test"
  }
```

3.When i try to import  `var module = require('test-module');` in `app.js` i got this error

> Cannot find module 'test-module'

Comment: I'm having the very same issue right now. It's weird because the module sits there in `node_modules` folder. Not sure why.

Comment: I think you missed the `main` section in your `package.json` inside the `test-module` package.

Answer (score 3):

> you can provide a path to a local directory that contains a package

```
{
  "name": "baz",
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
  }
}
```

and perform **npm install -s** or **npm install --save** [reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `test` folder has a `package.json`.

`test/package.json` should have a `"name"` field with the value `"test-module"` (ie, same name as the dependency in your root `package.json`.

My files:

**`test/package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "test-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**`test/index.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  t:() => console.log('t')
};
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "t",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "test-module": "file:test"
  }
}
```

**`app.js`**

```
t = require('test-module');
t.t();
```

This is working for me.

Comment: Yes i have the same

Comment: Do i need to install anyother packages??

Comment: No, you don't need any other packages. I tried exactly your code, and it worked for me. The only issue I got was when the name field was different.

Comment: I updated my answer to show all the files in my example. Can you show us the file structure inside `node_modules` folder?

Comment: my `test` folder is not in the `node_modules` folder do  i need to add manually in it??

Comment: no, you have to `npm install` or `npm i` from the root folder. That will automatically generate the `node_modules` folder with your `test-module` inside it.

Comment: I have deleted the entire node_modules and removed the test module after that `npm install`   `npm ERR! Could not install from "test" as it does not contain a package.json file`

Comment: But my package.json doesn't contain the local modules

Answer (score 0):

To add on @Blaze answer, if you follow the [steps](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) (Local Paths) to install a local module, it will sort out for you the local dependency in your package.json:

```
npm i ./test --save
```

That will produce the correct local dependency entry in your `dependencies` in the root `package.json`:

```
"test-module": "file:test"
```

assuming `test-module` is the name in the local dep `package.json`.

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Now the  module not found error is gone but i got another error `app.set` not a function

Comment: @iambatman: That would be a completely different problem :) I suggest you open another question for that one.

Comment: If i removed the import its gone

Comment: What's on your test-module? Sounds like there is an `app.set` which is not in the original question

Comment: It contains a `index.js` file with a function   i 've included that in the question

Comment: Where is `app.set`? Please update your question with the rest of the code, otherwise will be hard to help.